# HTTP error 500 exception occurred processing JSP

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee

I'm new to Java EE and I'm getting some parameters from a `JSP` page:

```
String cin = req.getParameter("cin");
    String nom = req.getParameter("nom");
    if(cin=="" && nom==""){
         listC= clientService.chercherTousLesClients();
    }

    req.setAttribute( "test", listC );
    this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher( "/chercherClient.jsp").forward( req, resp );
```

On the `JSP` file I have the code bellow:

```
<%
    ArrayList<Client> list;
    list = (ArrayList<Client>) request.getAttribute("test");

    %>
    <span><%=list.get(0).getCinClient() %><span>
```

And this is the error:

Etat HTTP 500 - An exception occurred processing JSP page /chercherClient.jsp at line 31

```
31:         <span><%=list.get(0).getCinClient() %><span>
```

Comment: check `listC` may be null?

Answer (score 0):

Error 500 means there was internal server error. I bet that you will find NullPointerException in application server logs.

The first of all you must not check for object equality: `cin==""`, use test for null and equals. The second - you must verifz that list is not null in jsp.

```
String cin = req.getParameter("cin");
String nom = req.getParameter("nom");
if ((cin == null || cin.isEmpty()) && (nom == null || nom.isEmpty())) {
     listC = clientService.chercherTousLesClients();
}

req.setAttribute( "test", listC);
this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher( "/chercherClient.jsp").forward( req, resp);
```

jsp:

```
<%
ArrayList<Client> list;
list = (ArrayList<Client>) request.getAttribute("test");
%>
<c:if test="list != null">
    <span><%=list.get(0).getCinClient() %><span>
</c:if>
```

Comment: why Scriptlets when JSTL in jsp?

Comment: Copy paste of the question :-) I did not have time to rewrite it.